# Does corrosion follow the law of conservation of mass?

Tags: metal

For e.g .Due to rusting , iron becomes weak .So it should become weak only if the amount of iron is reduced. Even if we say the reduced iron is now the rust ,the amount of rust practically is very less comparing to iron.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question in the title is yes.

Iron oxide flakes away from the iron so just looking at the iron would make you think that the mass has disappeared; it's actually on the surface below, unless someone has moved it.

Answer (score 1):

**In chemistry we assume the total mass of reactants to be conserved in after reaction** (except in the nuclear reactions, of course). It is a fundamental law and hold true everywhere.

Even in your question the Oxide layer formed above the iron makes the Ferrous Oxide which generally get removed, hence you think the mass had reduced.

Comment: +1. This is a GREAT answer. No idea why it was -1 before! I see you followed a Materials Science proposal in the past. I really wish they allowed it to be launched. If you don't mind another attempt at a Materials proposal, would you be so kind to commit to this? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=ZTUyZWY5OTQ1NDI4ZGVlMmU5MzM0ZThiZjNhOTRkYWFlMTA1NjM0OWEzOTZhYzlmMTBlNWQ4ZmIzYWE3MWFkN-4At28O9gekwyERVbYPhFIPwyHiajfB5BeMyrZKJaYV0 It started slow but lately it's been booming with 5 commitments/day and very soon it will reach 200.